# How to automatically append a query string using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to add new rewrite rule on htaccess to automatically append query string to the URL to whatever page the user will navigate. I tried this, but to no avail.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^subdirectory/index/([0-9]*)/?     /index.php?test=$1    [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add the *addMe* parameter into any incoming URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?addMe=1 [QSA]
```